# Using properties from application.properties while building bean in spring boot configuration annotated class?

Tags: spring-boot

We have properties defined in application.properties, is it appropriate to have the property pulled in a spring-boot @Configuration annotated class to be used for initializing the bean being created. Refer code snippet below

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${a.property.in.application.properties}")
    public String aProperty;

    @Bean
    MyClass myClassInstance() {
        return new MyClass(aProperty);
    }
}
```

Simplest example would be creating a datasource instance with url, driver, username, password configured in the application.properties

Is it appropriate?
What could be the possible consequences of continuing to use in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this approach for different things like cors configurations. There are probably also disadvantages, but so far it has only had advantages for me. I think it's most times better to have config values outside of the code. That allows you, for example, to use different profiles (local/dev/int/prod). But I would recommend to encrypt things like passwords. I'm using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/).

Comment: yes agreed, config values should be outside. That would be the next step in the application enhancement but till then we wanted to keep it this way. This helps.